# Button change color on toggle using jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I'm looking to change the color of the button or in this case the image of the button each time the button is selected on the toggle of the jQuery. Here's what I have so far for jQuery.

```
jQuery(document).ready(function () {
    jQuery('#occupation').hide();
    jQuery('#occupationshow').on('click', function (event) {
        jQuery('#occupation').toggle();
    });
});
```

And here's what I have for the button:

```
<button id="occupationshow">
    <img src="../SiteAssets/images/RAC/askcut/Occupation.jpg">
</button>
```

How can I get it so another image is displayed on the button when the button has been clicked?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The best way to do this is I think the following:

1. Create a sprite image of the two backgrounds for this button - so, one image file, with the two images side by side.
2. Set this image as the `background-image` of the element using CSS
3. Giving your `button#occupationshow` a fixed width/height, have the jquery modify the `background-position` of the image depending on the state of the button - simply put, depending on the current state of the button, the image will move left/right within `button#occupationshow` and you will only be able to see the relevant part at any one time.

You can as suggested modify the `src` attribute dynamically, but do bear in mind that with this approach the new image might take a moment to load once the button is clicked; with my approach both images are preloaded (as they are one image) and it's simply moving around, and so is instant.

[Sprites](http://www.w3schools.com/css/css_image_sprites.asp) are a great way of working, I'd recommend looking into them :-)

Answer (score 0):

You can use the [css](http://www.w3schools.com/jquery/jquery_css.asp) function of jquery to change the background image of a button on every click.

Answer (score 0):

`toggle()` by default is for showing/hiding. Use [attr()](http://api.jquery.com/attr/) with a callback function

```
jQuery('#occupationshow').on('click', function (event) {
    jQuery(this).find('img').attr('src', function(){
        var src = $(this).attr('src') == 'img1' ? 'img2' : 'img1';
        return src;
    });
});
```

Answer (score 0):

I guess you only have two images, right?
So what you can do is put two  tags, corresponding to both of your images, ont being set as "display: none".

```
<button id="occupationshow">
    <img src="../img1.jpg">
    <img src="../img2.jpg" style="display: none;">
</button>
```

And in jQuery your code will be :

```
jQuery('#occupationshow').on('click', function (e) {
    jQuery('#occupationshow img').toggle();
});
```

**Edit**: I re-read the first post again and don't know what made me guess OP only had two images... (the fact he wants to use "toggle", I guess)